# Android and roundedimageview: how to change the border color

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

In my XML layout, I use this code to create a specific shape for my imageview:

```
 <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/avatar"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:src="@drawable/adduserprofile"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:riv_border_width="5dip"
                app:riv_border_color="#ff9800"
                app:riv_mutate_background="true"
                app:riv_oval="false"
                app:riv_corner_radius_bottom_right="15dp"
                app:riv_corner_radius_top_left="15dp"
                app:riv_corner_radius_bottom_left="15dp"
                />
```

and then I load the image with Picasso in this way:

```
Picasso.get().load(url.memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE).into(p_avatar);
```

Is there any possibility to change the border color in Java by using Picasso or any other method?
I would like to change the border color depending on some user's events.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try to clean and rebuild the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Transformation** object to set properties of the shape. Use different Transformation object for different events.

```
Transformation transformation = new RoundedTransformationBuilder()
      .borderColor(Color.BLACK)
      .borderWidthDp(3)
      .cornerRadiusDp(30)
      .oval(false)
      .build();

Picasso.with(context)
.load(url)
.fit()
.transform(transformation)
.into(imageView);
```

You should check the [README](https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView#roundedimageview) of library before using it.

Answer (score 1):

try it.

```
((RoundedImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.avatar)).setBorderColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
((RoundedImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.avatar)).setBorderWidth(position * 5);
((RoundedImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.avatar)).setCornerRadius(position * 5);
((RoundedImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.avatar)).setImageBitmap(item.mBitmap);
((RoundedImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.avatar)).setScaleType(item.mScaleType);
```